# Spring Data Redis: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I'm having trouble connecting to Redis. I'm basically going through the example found here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial.

I have this in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

My config is the following:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {

@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
}


@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, String> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}

}
```

I have this in my application.yml

```
spring:
  redis:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
  timeout: 0
```

Just trying to execute the most basic command results in the exception in the title of this post:

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("1", "2");
```

Thanks for the help!